# .htaccess rewrite insert new url segment e.g. www.domain.com/wildcard == www.domain.com/new_segment/wildcard/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to do this globally via htaccess rewrite so any www.domain.com/wildcard/ would == www.domain.com/new_segment/wildcard/ but I can't seem to figure this out.

So far, I have the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/new_segment\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

For some reason, on the initial page load I get www.domain.com/new_segment/new_segment/ but if I go to www.domain.com/old_segment I would expect www.domain.com/new_segment/old_segment/ but I get www.domain.com/old_segment/ instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want that? Anyways, you can do it easier by putting desired files into a directory and a redirection from a file on the /old_segment to /new_segment.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new_segment
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new_segment/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will check to see if the `new_segment` isn't in the url, if it is then nothing will be redirected. If it isn't then `new_segment` will be added.